# Wakeful Broadcast receiver not receiving intents sent through sendBroadcast()

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I've implemented few services for my Android application. One of my service, `A_Service` checks if `B_Service` is running already, if not it sends Broadcasts through `sendBroadcast()` to reach the broadcast receiver `B_Broadcast_Receiver` of `B_Service`.

`B_Broadcast_Receiver` is registered both programatically on `A_Service` and on the `Android Manifest`. Also the call looks like this:

On `A_Service`

```java
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ....
        startBService()
        ...
        }
```

```java
 public void startBService(){
     if (!ServiceCheck.isRunning(B_Service.class, getBaseContext())){
     Intent startIntent = new Intent();
     startIntent.setClass(this, B_Broadcast_Receiver.class);
     startIntent.putExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME,    parentActivity);
     startIntent.putExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_SERVICE_NAME, parentService);
     //Send broadcast to start the B Wakeful BroadcastReceiver
     sendBroadcast(startIntent);
       }
    }
```

Wile debugging I find that the application never reaches the `onReceive()` of the wakeful broadcast receiver `B_Broadcast_Receiver` after the `sendBroadcast(startIntent)` call.

On `B_Broadcast_Receiver`:

```java
public class B_Broadcast_Receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context,B_Service.class);
            service.putExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME,intent.getStringExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_ACTIVITY_NAME));
            service.putExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_SERVICE_NAME,intent.getStringExtra(ServiceConstants.PARENT_SERVICE_NAME));
            Log.d("Wakeful LS", "Gonna start B service");
            startWakefulService(context, service);

        }
```

I'm confused on why this happens as I start service `A_Service` in an almost similar methodology from the main activity.

I appreciate your help on this!

---

Android Manifest

```
 <service
            android:name="org.abc.def.services.B_Service"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="org.abc.def.receivers.B_Broadcast_Receiver"/>
```

Comment: did you add the WAKE_LOCK permission to your manifest? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WAKE_LOCK. If so, can you show how do you add your B_Broadcast_Receiver in your manifest?

Comment: @mromer I've updated the post by adding how the manifest looks with regards to the B_Service and B_Broadcast_Receiver. Also , I've added the Wake lock permission already, as I mentioned my A_Service is also associated with a A_Broadcast_Receiver viz Wakeful too.

Comment: did you check that `sendBroadcast(startIntent);` is reached?

Comment: @mromer Yes, it reaches `sendBroadcast(startIntent)` but never reaches the `onReceive()` of `B_Broadcast_Receiver`. Also,I tried starting `B_Service` directly with `startService()` from `A_service` , it doesnt work to but if I do the same from the MainActivity it works.I dont understand where the problem is.

Comment: do your have services in separated libraries? or are they in the same project?

Comment: @mromer They are in the same project!